# Stored procedure with @variable server name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a new stored procedure `sp_sync_table` (in SQL Server 2012) which accepts one parameter (linked server name). However jut declaring the `@linkedServerName` variable is not enough. The `CREATE PROCEDURE` directive fails because it cannot resolve the `@linkedServerName` unless `@linkedServerName` is **SET** to a specific name.

It fails with error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_sync_table, Line 31
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.)

Obviously I cannot provide a specific name, that has to be passed in through the

```
exec sp_sync_table server_name
```

This is the failing part:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_sync_table
    @linkedServerName AS VARCHAR(50)
AS BEGIN
.
.
.
DECLARE cursorX CURSOR FOR

SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM @linkedServerName.[db-name].[dbo].[table]

OPEN cursorX
.
.
.
```

What would be the workaround for this scenario ?

Comment: I think dynamic sql is going to be your only option

Comment: Well, not sure what you are doing inside the cursor, but is it possible to create this procedure at the linked server, and just call the procedure remotely, instead of trying to munge all this together in dynamic SQL on the caller side?

Comment: ..that would be too easy (the linked server is not mine) so unfortunately not :)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use dynamic sql?  I know it's not the safe way to go about doing it, but you could place your query in a string and execute the string.  Just be super careful of what the user passes in for the @linkedServerName.  Obviously you will be executing whatever you allow your user to enter.  Not sure how this will work with a cursor though - I've never tried.

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE sp_sync_table

    @linkedServerName AS VARCHAR(50)

AS BEGIN

.
.
.
DECLARE queryToExecute varchar(max)
select  queryToExecute = 'DECLARE cursorX CURSOR FOR'
select queryToExecute = queryToExecute + 'SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM'
select queryToExecute = queryToExecute + ' ' + @linkedServerName + '.[db-name].[dbo].[table]'
select queryToExecute = queryToExecute + 'OPEN cursorX...'
exec(queryToExecute)
```

Comment: I have tried this (similar exec statement) with no luck. I just tried your version (above) and it throws errors that col1, col2, col3 do not exist...  Any ideas ? Could it be thsat this worked on older SQLs only ?

Comment: Do you actually have a column called  linkedServerName.[db-name].[dbo].[table].[Col1]?   a schema named db-name and a table called table is a bit unusual.  Older sql generally works on newer, that isn't an issue here.

Comment: I suggest you use dynamic SQL to get the data into a loca staging tablem the nrun your cursor over that - it will be alot simpler to maintain and possibly faster (depdning on how many remote record)

Comment: (to: Twelfth)...I am not sure I understand this question. I do have the above mentioned columns but obviously since the linkedServerName is a variable, it should not make the difference. Or does it ?

Comment: (to:macoms01)... you were right the first time, I was executing just the QUERY statement itself ('SELECT col1, col2....) and when I included in the same exec statement the additional 'DECLARE cursorX CURSOR FOR' it went through! Thank you.

Comment: ...actually, it accepts the SP as valid code but executing the procedure fails terribly. So.. back to square 1...

Comment: SOLVED!!! macoms01 is correct but for some reason exec(@sql) does not work. However when I use: execute sp_executesql @sql it woks like a charm! I am voting you up since no one submitted a better answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Don't forget to filter the heck out of the server name variable for sql injection!